# How to get the Future list in order when calling the executorService.invokeAll(callables)?

Tags: java, multithreading

i hv the following code

```
final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(ipAddressList.size());
        final Set<Callable<JsonObject>> callables = new HashSet<Callable<JsonObject>>();
        for (final String remoteHostName : ipAddressList)
        {
            callables.add(new Callable<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public JsonObject call()
                        throws ConnectionFailedException
                {
                    return connectToHost(remoteHostName, options, attributes);
                }
            });
        }

        List<Future<JsonObject>> futures = null;
        try
        {
            futures = executorService.invokeAll(callables);
        }
        catch (final InterruptedException e)
        {...
        }

        for (final Future<JsonObject> future : futures)
        {
          ..}
```

Now the problem is, exception can occur in any of the thread, but i dont have any ways to identify for which IP address the exception. Is there any ways to get the futures in the same order as the order of callables.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't even try to do something as brittle and silly as relying on the order, but include the address in the exception for example? Note that you're using a `HashSet`, so you don't have an order to begin with.

Comment: Although it's probably not *specified*, I think that the order will likely be the same (if you used a `List` instead of a `HashSet`, this would be easier to check). But I generally agree that you should not really *rely* on that for anything else than short-time, highly controlled local debugging.

Comment: @Kayaman But i am getting generic ExecutionException returned from third party APIC for which i dont have control over to add the ipaddress

Comment: What's that `CallFailedException` then?

Comment: @Kayaman got the solution by adding the ip in the exception. thank u..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to get the Futures in same Order as Callables..Note that it runs in a multi threaded environment and there is no specific order on how threads will be executed. I can think of 2 approach here:

1. IP address as part of exception message and you can extract from there
2. Yon can catch the exception in Callable and wrap it as part of your result. May be you can use javalangs Either for this?

Comment: But i am getting generic ExecutionException returned from third party APIC for which i dont have control over to add the ipaddress